# Move prediction in a chess game?

Tags: math, statistics, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, chess

Is it possible to find the pattern of a chess player and predict the most appropriate next move?

Is there any algorithm can solve this problem? Can you suggest any reference to find out the algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean by pattern of a chess player? In chess AFAIK, a good move is not played according to the other player's playing pattern but according to the board position.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: the pattern strategy to win.

Answer (score 3):

You could try it with this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_chess#Leaf_evaluation and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_function and also take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Thought_%28chess_computer%29

Maybe that helps...

Comment: @Macro Frost:  Thanks a lot answer.I gone trough the links you mentioned in your answer. Those are talking about evaluation of move. My question is slightly different,e.g. psychiatrists are talking about behavioral pattern on the similar line can we find the pattern of strategic plan to win and with knowledge can we predict next move.

Answer (score 3):

[Programmer Puzzle: Encoding a chess board state throughout a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831386/programmer-puzzle-encoding-a-chess-board-state-throughout-a-game) 
[Chess game in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055332/chess-game-in-javascript)

[Is there a perfect algorithm for chess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297577/is-there-a-perfect-algorithm-for-chess?rq=1)

This could help, technically there's no computer with power enough to solve a chess problem perfectly.

search more on stackoverflow for more views !

Answer (score 3):

To a degree. An easy means of prediction in AI is the use of [Case-based reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-based_reasoning) agents.

Assuming your chess pattern detector has been trained on a fairly large number of games, it will indeed be able to guess an opponent's moves based on current board state and previous moves. The correctness of its suppositions are of course dependent on how many games it has been trained on, as well as the content of games it has been trained on.